# misleading line number in error message: XTSE0120: No character data is allowed between top-level elements

Tags: xslt, saxon

this is a self-answered post, since it took me some time to find the reason for the following XTSE0120.
I'm quite new to XSLT and made a mistake and put some text outside `<xsl:template>`:

```
bellack@bellack-TP-T430u:~$ cat -n /tmp/x.xsl
     1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     2 <xsl:stylesheet 
     3   version="2.0" 
     4   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     5 >
     6 <xsl:output method="text"/>
     7 <xsl:template name="build" match="/">
     8 <!-- 
     9   a lot of xslt code lines 
    10   -->
    11 </xsl:template>
    12 ****** misplaced text ****************
    13 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

As this is not allowed, I got error XTSE120, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#err-XTSE0120:

```
bellack@bellack-TP-T430u:~/workspace/tembanking/generator/crud$ java -jar ../lib/saxon9.jar -xsl:/tmp/x.xsl -s:/dev/null
Error at xsl:template on line 7 of file:/tmp/x.xsl:
  XTSE0120: No character data is allowed between top-level elements
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

But the Error is reported for line 7, and since x.xsl had some hundred lines, I was searching for something wrong around line 7 in vain, where the error was in fact at the end of the file.

I don't know if other XSLT processors than saxon also give this misleading error message.

Hope that helps somebody ...

Udo

Comment: Consider to file problems with a particular software on the forum or bug database of the product, for Saxon see https://saxonica.plan.io/.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. If you want to self-answer a question, you should post both a question and an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Saxon only keeps line number information for element nodes, not for text nodes, so we have difficulty reporting an accurate position for the rare case where the error is in a text node.

Comment: Thank you for this technical explanation. I was irritated by the fract that the reported error refers to the beginning of xsl:template which is in fact correct. Maybe there is a way to report something like "No character data allowed ... after xsl:template". But, of course, this is not very important if you know some xslt basics which I do now 8-)